# How to set an image for a row?

Tags: qt

I want to add text (at the beginning of a row) and an image at the end of the row.

I can set the text but how to set an image at the end of the row item in `QTreeWidgetItem`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just set for example two columns in QTreeWidget and then set text in first one and icon in second one:

```
QTreeWidgetItem *newItem = new QTreeWidgetItem;
newItem->setText(0, "Something");
newItem->setIcon(1, QIcon("Path to your icon"));

myTreeWidget->addTopLeveItem(newItem);
```

Or instread of setting icon you can just set foreground:

```
newItem->setForeground(QBrush(QPixmap("Path to your image")));
```

which may be better for your problem.

Comment: Thanks Blood ,the first solution is works for me.Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Blood: how do you use a myTreeWidget->setForeground? I have tested your solution, but it draws nothing. I have tried also myTreeWidget->setBackground, but it tiles the image.

Comment: @VladyslavSavchenko I found using `newItem->setData(1, Qt::DecorationRole, QPixmap("Path to your image"));` worked